# HTTP put method causes 404

Tags: spring, rest

I'm trying to use REST for some minor operations.
the Get operation and Post operation work just fine, only the PUT operation gives me issues.

I am working with 2 dispatchers (one that maps to "/rest/*" and one that maps to "/web/*" and as far as i'm aware my config files are correct (else the rest wouldn't work either?).

To test I use a chrome plugin called Postman btw.

At the moment I'm using only one rest controller:

```
@Controller
public class RestController {

@Autowired
BlogPostServiceImp blogPostService;

@RequestMapping(value= "/getPosts", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Collection<Post> getposts()
{
    return blogPostService.getPosts();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/post/{uername}/{description}/{speciality}/{url}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void addPost(@PathVariable("username") String username,
                    @PathVariable("description") String description,
                    @PathVariable("speciality") String speciality,
                    @PathVariable("url") String url)
{
    Post p = new Post(blogPostService.getId(), "2014", username, description, speciality, url);
    blogPostService.addPost(p);
}

}
```

As i said earlier, the GET request works but the PUT returns a 404.

edit: the logfiles from glassfish confirm this:

[2014-10-30T14:28:21.180+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1414675701180] [levelValue: 900] [[
  No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MvcSpringBlogREST/rest/post] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher2']]

Comment: How are you calling that method? Because it wouldn't work from a webpage, as web browsers only do GET/POST

Comment: @Vld I'm using a chrome plugin called Postman to emulate the calls.

Comment: Use the RESTClient plug in Firefox. If it doesnt work, could u send me the request url you were testing with? Type in here

Comment: @ManilLiyanage the chrome plugin should work just fine.  

http://localhost:8080/MvcSpringBlogREST/rest/post/  

that's the url i'm working with that isn't working.  

http://localhost:8080/MvcSpringBlogREST/rest/getPosts

this maps to the get method and works just fine

Comment: @killernerd please specify your full request url. With the values you used

Comment: @ManilLiyanage

PUT /MvcSpringBlogREST/rest/post/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

test
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

testdesc
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="speciality"

testspec
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="url"

testurl
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C

at least if that's what you wanted

Comment: Try sending the following url..  http://localhost:8080/MvcSpringBlogREST/rest/post/testuser/test/test/test    using the rest client in firefox with the request type as PUT.

Comment: @ManilLiyanage I installed firefox and some random RESTclient to try it out but, as expected, this also returns a 404

Answer (score 0):

Try using a chrome addon (app) called Advanced Rest Client
chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/RestClient.html

Choose that you will be doing Put instead of Get/Post

Comment: That was just to enable you specify that you want to do PUT. postman do the same job though.. Are you specifying that you want application/json response? You have to set response that you are expecting.. try entering this on the header section.. Accept: application/json

Comment: I did, the funny thing is that it returns 404 on a put request but 405 (method not supported) on a get or post request (to the same url). go figure...

Comment: 405 is because you have specified that it has to be PUT.. What uri/path are you using.. Are you adding context - if any??

Comment: yes i know but isn't it weird that the exact same url returns a 405 when treated as a post or GET yet returns 404 when set as PUT? I'd expect GET and POST to also result in a 404, not a 405. 405 indicates it can find the resource but it's simply not supported. I am adding header date through the postman plugin and have set the accept to "application/json".
See my responses above.

Comment: You have the first url (/MvcSpringBlogREST/rest/getPosts) as GET still  and second (/MvcSpringBlogREST/post/name/my_name/xx/xx) as PUT. Change the first method to be PUT and use the right path on the second url. The first url should not be working as you have specified... Path variables specify and url are required

Comment: i kinda lost you there. The first method is supposed to be a get, I use it to retrieve the posts... And as far as i can tell it works.

The first method (specified as GET) works as intended.
The second method (specified as PUT) doesn't work. If I use postman to simulate a PUT on this URL it comes back as a 404, if i try to simulate a POST or GET call on that same url (which is defined as put) it returns a 405.